# Ruby script/console and Ruby script/server using two different DBs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console

Has anyone seen where script/console and script/server load two different databases (though both report using the same)? Here's the first output

```
$ script/server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.5 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2010-03-21 15:54:05] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2010-03-21 15:54:05] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10) [i386-mingw32]
[2010-03-21 15:54:05] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=7148 port=3000
```

No errors. I then run my standard code for entering a form - no problems.

Checking the Dev Database (.yml at bottom):

```
mysql> select * from books;
[...]
| 712 | Book | Book Name | 2010-03-21 22:29:22 | 2010-03-21 22:29:22 |
[...]
712 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The code CLEARLY saved it seconds ago

And now here's the output of script/console:

```
$ script/console
Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.5)
>> Book.all
=> []
```

Nothing. Further, upon further inspection, it's using the production database, but I can't figure out why. Any thoughts here? All consoles have been closed and reopened.

**UPDATE:** Requested .yml file (can't see how it'd be helpful (user name and password are all the same for each)) -

```
development:
  adapter: mysql  
  database: BooksDBdev
  username: <user name>
  password: <long string>
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql
  database: BooksDBtest
  username: <user name>
  password: <long string>
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: mysql
  database: BooksDB
  username: <user name>
  password: <long string>
  timeout: 5000
```

**Updated 2**: Here's the output when I force the console environment.

```
$ script/console development
Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.5)
>> Book.all
=> []
>> exit

$ ruby script/console development
Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.5)
>> Book.all
=> []
```

Just FYI, I don't have RAILS_ENV specified in my environment variables.

Comment: Can you be more specific? _What_ is using the production database? You said you checked 'the dev database'... Maybe paste your database.yml?

Comment: Done... the command 'ruby script/console' uses the production database, despite reporting that it's using the development database.

The command 'ruby script/server' uses the development database, as it should.

Comment: What happens if you use the environment name explicitly?  For instance script/server development  and  script/console development

Comment: same deal - the despite the console saying "development", it's not using the development database. I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running these at the same time, in different terminals? If so, you may need to do `reload!` in your console for the database changes to show up.

Comment: Same machine, different terminals... yes - but I've closed all the terminals many times. Regardless, it's not a model change - as you can see, it's the data access that's messed up (accessing the wrong DB).

Comment: Oh. Try commenting out the production & test sections of your .yml file - maybe it'll throw a useful error.

Comment: Yeah, when I do, the ruby script/console fails! As I said, weirdly, even though it claims it's using development, it seems to be using production. But not the server!

Answer (score -1):

Pluralized model name? Yikes! Do you have another model called Book or something?

Comment: Not real names :) ... it's not plural irl.